# Are there any characters in the Japanese edition, other than Kain and Tyro, that can use Axes?

Tags: final-fantasy-record-keeper

I've drawn two Hammerhead Axes with my pulls on the slot machine thus far. It's a nice 4* Axe. Problem is, only Kain and the Record Keeper character can use Axes. Now, an Axe for Kain is great, (even if it's FF12 synergized, sadly). But I'm mainly using Tyro as a healer and his physical attack stat is, to put it mildly, hot garbage. So the logical thing to do then, is to combine the two Hammerheads into a Hammerhead + and get a nice 5* weapon for Kain! Unless, of course, there's a new character coming down the pipe that will also be able to make great use of an Axe.

So, are there any such characters, other than Kain and Tyro, *currently availiable* in the Japanese edition of the game?

Comment: NB: The Japanese edition of Final Fantasy Record Keeper has had substantially more content and characters released to date than the Global edition. Thus, in many ways, it can act as a preview of forthcoming content. I am not seeking speculative answers, only concrete information about the Japanese edition of the game. Any inferences drawn are my own after that. Guesses will be down voted mercilessly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [Chrysalis Wiki](http://chrysaliswiki.com/people:characters-in-record-keeper), the following characters are currently in FFRK (Japan or Global) and are able to wield axes:

[Adelbert Steiner (IX)](http://chrysaliswiki.com/people:adelbert-steiner#toc13)
[Cecil - Paladin (IV)](http://chrysaliswiki.com/people:cecil-harvey#toc25) (Paladin Cecil doesn't have axes in Global, so I'm not sure if the wiki is inaccurate or a difference between Japan and Global)
[Golbez (IV)](http://chrysaliswiki.com/people:golbez#toc13)
[Josef (II)](http://chrysaliswiki.com/people:josef#toc9)
[Kain (IV)](http://chrysaliswiki.com/people:kain-highwind#toc22)
[Leonhart (II)](http://chrysaliswiki.com/people:leonhart#toc8)
[Luneth (III)](http://chrysaliswiki.com/people:luneth#toc11)
[Ricard (II)](http://chrysaliswiki.com/people:ricard-highwind#toc9)
[Tyro (Core)](http://chrysaliswiki.com/people:tyro)
[Warrior of Light (I)](http://chrysaliswiki.com/people:warrior-of-light#toc21)